# Webpack: Importing font-awesome fails because it can't find the fonts

Tags: sass, webpack, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome from NPM and trying to use it with webpack. But, I get an error that the fonts can't be found. The fonts reside under `~/Projects/GrailLuck/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts`.

I import font-awesome in my sass file like so:

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome";
```

My loaders:

```
loaders: [
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules|app.js/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015']
    }
},
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "sass") ],
    loader: 'style!css!sass?includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/compass-mixins/lib')
},
{
    test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
},
{
    test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
},
{
    test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
},
{
    test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "file"
},
{
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
}]
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader?includePaths[]=/home/spock/Projects/GrailLuck/web/~/compas
s-mixins/lib!./src/sass/app.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg in /home/spo
ck/Projects/GrailLuck/web/src/sass
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader?includePaths[]=/home/spock/Projects/GrailLuck/web/~/compass-mixi
ns/lib!./src/sass/app.scss 6:10469-10520
```

There's multiple errors the same as the above. One for each font type.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there's a package called [font-awesome-sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-sass-loader). Works perfectly and doesn't feel hackish like other solutions around the web.

Comment: Would be great if you would expand on this.

Comment: The instructions for usage are in the docs. Pretty simple to be honest.

Comment: Well, it was not simple for me. Maybe you are too smart, or I am too dumb, but the fact is that it would be great when someone googles and finds this question, if they had something more than just "use this".

Comment: Seriously, I still don't understand how is this including the font-awesome sass partial? Can we use inside our Sass? The example only shows a webpack config.

Comment: I keep coming to this question because I am trying to use font-awesome-sass-loader and have followed the doc, but the fonts are being pack with relative file URLs and failing to load. Docs don't cover that part and this question doesn't answer it either.. would be nice to see an answer with a full example.